# How can i Search using two variables in two different fields in MySQL

Tags: php, sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

This is the code that I have -- I can't make it work:

```
<?php require_once('../Connections/User.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form1")) {
  $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE grade SET GSCode=%s, GSem=%s, GYear=%s, Grade=%s WHERE GStudNo=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['GSCode'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['GSem'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['GYear'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Grade'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['GStudNo'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_User, $User);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $User) or die(mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db($database_User, $User);
$query_Recordset1 = sprintf("SELECT * 
           FROM grade 
          WHERE GSCode = '%s' AND GStudNo = '%s'",
        mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['a']),
        mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['b']));

$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $User) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM grade WHERE GSCode = '$_POST[a]' $$ GStudNo =  '$_POST[b]'";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $User) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
  <table align="center">
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">GStudNo:</td>
      <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['GStudNo']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">GSCode:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="GSCode" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_Recordset1['GSCode'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">GSem:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="GSem" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_Recordset1['GSem'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">GYear:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="GYear" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_Recordset1['GYear'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Grade:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Grade" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_Recordset1['Grade'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Update record" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="form1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="GStudNo" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['GStudNo']; ?>" />
</form>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($Recordset1);
?>
```

Comment: error message? And think about preventing `SQL injections` (-> http://de.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)

Comment: Post the actual PHP that constructs the query, not the intended final SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AND instead of &&

And use sprintf to protect your variables:

```
sprintf("SELECT * 
           FROM grade 
          WHERE GSCode = '%s' AND GStudNo = '%s'",
        mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['a']),
        mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['b']));
```

Comment: [%u is for integer -- the sample is using strings (%s)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).  I'd also wrap the POST variable retrieval in mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: Sorry, I assumed GSCode and GStudNo were integers. Very wrong

Comment: i still get the same error 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$$ GStudNo = '07-08-0066'' at line 1

Answer (score 2):

SQL uses `AND` in a condition, not `&&`.

Comment: i cant still make it work heres the error 
_You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$$ GStudNo = '07-08-0066'' at line 1_

Answer (score 1):

Use and not &&.

```
mysql_query("select * from table where `one`='$_POST[one]' and `two`='$_POST[two]'") or die (mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean

```
"SELECT * FROM grade WHERE GSCode = '{$_POST['a']}' and GStudNo = '{$_POST['b']}'"
```

Not only the 'and', but also the inclusion of the post value. Or did you actually mean to earch for the literal text: '$_POST[s]'? Which would still not work in the way you posted, because the PHP string parser tries to evaluate `$_POST` if you don't escape it.